# Pandas: How to drop self correlation from correlation matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, correlation

I'm trying to find highest correlations for different columns with pandas. I know can get correlation matrix with

```
df.corr()
```

I know I can get the highest correlations after that with

```
df.sort() 
df.stack() 
df[-5:]
```

The problem is that these correlation also contain values for column with the column itself (1). How do I remove these columns that contain correlation with self? I know I can remove them by removing all 1 values but I don't want to do that as there might be actual 1 correlations too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently found even cleaner answer to my question, you can compare multi-index levels by value.

This is what I ended using.

```
corr = df.corr().stack()
corr = corr[corr.index.get_level_values(0) != corr.index.get_level_values(1)]
```

Answer (score 13):

Say you have

```
corrs = df.corr()
```

Then the problem is with the diagonal elements, IIUC. You can easily set them to some negative value, say -2 (which will necessarily be lower than all correlations) with

```
np.fill_diagonal(corrs.values, -2)
```

---

**Example**

(Many thanks to @Fabian Rost for the improvement & @jezrael for the DataFrame)

```
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame( {
    'one':[0.1, .32, .2, 0.4, 0.8], 
    'two':[.23, .18, .56, .61, .12], 
    'three':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3], 
    'four':[.34, .75, .91, .19, .21], 
    'zive': [0.1, .32, .2, 0.4, 0.8], 
    'six':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3],
    'drive':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3]})
corrs = df.corr()
np.fill_diagonal(corrs.values, -2)
>>> corrs
    drive   four    one six three   two zive
drive   -2.000000   -0.039607   -0.747365   1.000000    1.000000    0.238102    -0.747365
four    -0.039607   -2.000000   -0.489177   -0.039607   -0.039607   0.159583    -0.489177
one -0.747365   -0.489177   -2.000000   -0.747365   -0.747365   -0.351531   1.000000
six 1.000000    -0.039607   -0.747365   -2.000000   1.000000    0.238102    -0.747365
three   1.000000    -0.039607   -0.747365   1.000000    -2.000000   0.238102    -0.747365
two 0.238102    0.159583    -0.351531   0.238102    0.238102    -2.000000   -0.351531
zive    -0.747365   -0.489177   1.000000    -0.747365   -0.747365   -0.351531   -2.000000
```

Comment: You could also have negative values for correlations. So it would be better to set them to a value smaller than -1.

Comment: Maybe you can add sample `df=pd.DataFrame( {'one':[0.1, .32, .2, 0.4, 0.8], 'two':[.23, .18, .56, .61, .12], 'three':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3], 'four':[.34, .75, .91, .19, .21], 'zive': [0.1, .32, .2, 0.4, 0.8], 'six':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3], 'drive':[.9, .3, .6, .5, .3]})`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about fill_diagonal. This solves the issue nicely.

Comment: (I think I'll just set them to NaN and then just drop all NaNs)

Comment: @mikkom great idea, `NaN`s will sort at the bottom AFAICS.

Answer (score 2):

Fill them with NaN rather than a fake number

```py
import numpy as np
np.fill_diagonal(corr_matrix.values, np.nan) # automatically inplace
```

NaN is supported by both seaborn and plotly correlation matrices

Answer (score 0):

another solution would be a stack.

```
s = corr.stack(-1)
# remove where corr is 1 
s = s[s != 1]
# convert to matrix again
s.unstack()
```

or

```
corr.values[np.tril_indices_from(corr.values, k=0)] = np.nan
```